# Getting 'created by' for a folder in Sharepoint document library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I want to get the author(who created) a folder in a Sharepoint Online using PnP PowerShell. The time last modified I can get it, but the field author I cannot get it. I know that can be two different fields, author and modifier, but I cannot get any from this.

For the folders:

```
$folder = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $folderPath -ItemName $subfolderName
Write-Host "URL      : " $folder.ServerRelativeUrl
Write-Host "Name     : " $folder.Name
Write-Host "Modified : " $folder.TimeLastModified
# above are ok, but $folder has no author property
# same next line fails, Author it does not exist
$folder= Get-PnPFolder -Url "$folderPath/$subfolderName" -Includes ListItemAllFields.Author
```

For the files, is easy I use:

```
Get-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $file.ServerRelativeUrl -Path $destinationfolder -FileName $file.Name -AsFile
$f = Get-PnPFile  -Url "$($folderUrl)/$($file.Name)" -AsListItem
$fileDetails = @{            
    File = "$($destinationFolder)/$($file.Name)"
    Author = $f["Author"].Email
    Created = $f["Created"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just find the solution, if anyone need:

```
context = Get-PnPContext
$context.load($context.Web)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documente")
$context.Load($list)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$camlQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$camlQuery.ViewXml ="<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><Value Type='Text'>/server/folder/relativepath</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
$allItems=$list.GetItems($camlQuery)
$context.Load($allItems)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($item in $allItems){
   Write-Host "##############"
   Write-Host $item["FileRef"]
   $item["Author"].Email
   $item["Modified"]
}
```

Comment: Often you just need to make sure to load a property - 
$context.Load($folder.ListItemAllFields);
$context.ExecuteQuery();
$folder.ListItemAllFields["Author"].LookupValue;